# Cron job has a different output then running a script in the browser

Tags: php, linux, unix, cron

I'm running the following code on my server, the script works fine in the browser but when i try it in a cronjob or through shell logged in as root i get a totally different output.

output through the browser:

- logs in and gets the page i want

output through shell / cron:

- doesn't seem to login, but gets the contents of the page redirecting me back to the login page.

i'm using red hat linux 5

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.domain.com/shopper_lookup.asp"; // the url where to send the request
$fields_send = 'shopper_username=USERNAME&shopper_password=PASSWORD&Validate=1';
$agent = "Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en-GB) Presto/2.1.1";
$reffer = "http://www.domain.com/login.html";
$cookie_file_path = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/store/cookie"; // Cookie File Path with CHMOD 777

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_send);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result_source = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($ch);

echo $result_source;




$url = "http://www.domain.com/receipt.asp?ms=&order_id=ordernumber"; // the url where to send the request
$agent = "Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en-GB) Presto/2.1.1";
$reffer = "http://www.domain.com/contents.asp?ms=";
$cookie_file_path = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/store/cookie"; // Cookie File Path with CHMOD 777

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result_source = curl_exec($ch);


echo $result_source; // Print the result page


?>
```

Comment: are you running this script (from cron) as root?

Comment: What do you mean by "through the browser"? I assume this is a script, and through the browser would be accessing it via the url? Also what is the cron job command? And what privileges are you running at it?

Comment: I logged in through SSH as root and ran this command... /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/store/curl_test.php      if i goto http://www.domain.com/store/curl_test.php   it works

Comment: also this script used to work ok on our old server (as a cron job) until we moved to the new server :/

Comment: Running PHP as a shell script you dont have any of the 'web' facilities you would have going through a browser - so cookies, sessions etc would not work (which may well be why you're getting sent back to login screen?)

Comment: Hi Doug yep I think it's the same issue but im not sure how i can get the script to run with the same web facilities?

Comment: You claim that this script used to work on another server from commandline and that is works when called from a browser. Since PHP usually uses different php.ini configs for webserver and commandline usages, a comparison of the two configs (if present) could yield into the right direction.

Comment: yep your right madflow, I found out the reason PHP safe_mode was set to On in /etc/php.ini and safe_mode is set to Off in the Apache configuration files, its all working now! cheers

Comment: @Doug, the Cookie options in curl are not php's $_COOKIE global, so they will work in this case, @Stu.. try making the curl request to dummy script and print_r the `$_REQUEST` and `$_COOKIE`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the output of the command if you execute it as your web user (typically www-data) with

```
su www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/store/curl_test.php
```

If that works then this is a permissions error so ensure the user you're running the cron job as can write to the file "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/store/cookie".

Comment: I found out the reason PHP safe_mode was set to On in /etc/php.ini and safe_mode is set to Off in the Apache configuration files, its all working now! cheers